# Java & XML: Fixing a few things

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I'm making an attempt to load my npc drops for a game via xml. I've started the loading processes but I'm encountered a few problems. First of all, I can only have 1 drop per npc without creating another case of 'newNpc' with the same npc id or I get a load error. I'd like to have multiple drops per npc. Also I need help reading and using a definition by rarity. Example: 
if (Math.random(100) > 95) {
// Drop VERY_RARE item here
|

My XStreamUtil Class (loads xml files):

```
package server.engine.util;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import server.game.entity.npc.impl.drops.NpcDropDefinition;
import server.game.entity.npc.impl.drops.NpcDropDefinition.LoadDropDefinitions;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.Sun14ReflectionProvider;

public class XStreamUtil {

    private static XStreamUtil instance = new XStreamUtil();
    private static XStream xStream = new XStream(new Sun14ReflectionProvider());

    public static XStreamUtil getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static XStream getxStream() {
        return xStream;
    }

    static {
        xStream.alias("newNpc", NpcDropDefinition.class);
    }

    public static void loadAllFiles() throws IOException {
        LoadDropDefinitions.load();
    }

    public static void writeXML(Object object, File file) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        try {
            xStream.toXML(object, out);
            out.flush();
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

}
```

My Xml Definition Class:

```
package server.game.entity.npc.impl.drops;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.List;

import server.engine.util.XStreamUtil;

/**
 * NpcDropDefinition.java
 * 
 * @author Notorious
 */

public class NpcDropDefinition {

    private int npcId, itemId, itemAmount;
    private DropRarity dropRarity;

    enum DropRarity {
        CONSTANT,
        COMMON,
        UNCOMMON,
        RARE,
        VERY_RARE;
    }

    /**
     * @return the npcId
     */
    public int getNpcId() {
        return npcId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the itemId
     */
    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the itemAmount
     */
    public int getItemAmount() {
        return itemAmount;
    }

    public DropRarity getDropRarity() {
        return dropRarity;
    }

    public static class LoadDropDefinitions {

        /**
         * Holds all of the definitions for prayer
         */
        private static NpcDropDefinition[] def = null;

        public static NpcDropDefinition[] getDefinitions() {
            return def;
        }

        /**
         * Loads the definitions of pvm points from the XML file
         * 
         * @throws FileNotFoundException
         */
        public static void load() throws FileNotFoundException {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<NpcDropDefinition> XMLlist = (List<NpcDropDefinition>) XStreamUtil
                    .getxStream().fromXML(
                            new FileInputStream("./data/xml/npcDrops.xml"));
            def = new NpcDropDefinition[XMLlist.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < def.length; i++) {
                def[i] = XMLlist.get(i);
            }
            if (def.length > 1 || def.length < 1)
                System.out.println("[Npc-Drops]: " + def.length
                        + " npc drops have been loaded..");
            else
                System.out
                        .println("[Npc-Drops]: Only one npc drop has been loaded..");
        }
    }
}
```

My Drop Handler class:

```
package server.game.entity.npc.impl.drops;

import server.Server;
import server.game.entity.Client;
import server.game.entity.npc.NpcHandler;
import server.game.entity.player.PlayerHandler;

/**
 * NpcDropHandler.java
 * 
 * @author Notorious
 */

public class NpcDropHandler {

    public void dropItems(int i) {
        Client c = (Client) PlayerHandler.players[NpcHandler.npcs[i]
                .getKillerIndex()];
        if (c != null) {
            Server.itemHandler.createGroundItem(c, 1, NpcHandler.npcs[i].absX,
                    NpcHandler.npcs[i].absY, 1, c.playerId);
        }
    }
}
```

My Current Xml file:

```
<list>
    <newNpc>
        <npcId>1265</npcId>
        <itemId>995</itemId>
        <itemAmount>10</itemAmount>
        <dropRarity>COMMON</dropRarity>
    </newNpc>
</list>
```

Comment: Can I recommend using a map which either maps the NPC to his drop loot OR making drop sets, and then mapping the NPC to the dropset?

What I'm seeing here is really a poor way of doing this IMO when you're making it from scratch. However, having this data externalized to XML files might be alright. But you should put much more thought (and read) in this, as this will be a fundamental piece of your game you won't have time for revisiting later.

Comment: I was just trying to look for a way to hold the drops externally while learning usage of xml.